# Variable rendering while performing an action in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So, I am trying to get the item of a dictonary in a conditional rendering format. This is the way I tried:

```
const selectionDict = {
Kcal: 'items.energy',
Protein: 'items.proteins',
Carbohydrates: 'items.carbohydrates',
Fat: 'items.fat',
Overview: ''
  };

let renderCard = ({ item }) => {
    
    return(
      <View style={[styles.renderCardContainer, styles.margins]}>
        <View style={{width: '85%'}}>
          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.productName}>{item.product_name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.consumedQuantity}>
            <Text>{item.consumed_quantity}</Text>
            <Text> gram</Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.energy}>
          <Text style={styles.energyText}>{selectionDict[Object.keys(selectionDict)[0]]}</Text>
        </View>
     </View>
    );
  };
```

---Edited---

```
 <FlatList
          data={retrievedData}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem = {renderCard}
        />
```

However, currently I get 'item.energy' rendered, but I want to have the value of items.energy...
How do I get this?

Comment: I would expect this to happen. `Object.keys(selectionDict)[0]` picks the first key of the object `selectionDict`. You then use this key to pick the value from the exact same object and this value is a string called `items.energy`. What exactly do you expect to happen? Do you want to call `item.energy` from the destructured item object in `renderCard`?

Comment: So I have a json object called {items} which I want to call in the {renderCard} object. I get why it renders as you describe, but how can I change that?

Comment: Is it `items` or `item`?

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry it is `item` indeed

Comment: And `item` contains a key called `energy`? Can you show me the object definition of `item`?

Comment: Yess it does! Whenever I type `<Text style={styles.energyText}>{item.energy}</Text>` it shows the desired number

Comment: I added some things to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `item` object contains a key called `energy`, and you want to pick the value for this key depending on a value in `selectionDict`, I would change `selectionDict` to the following.

```js
const selectionDict = {
    Kcal: 'energy',
    Protein: 'proteins',
    Carbohydrates: 'carbohydrates',
    Fat: 'fat',
    Overview: ''
};
```

Then, you can pick it as you initially wanted, but this time by accessing the `item` objects value for the key `energy`:

```js
item[selectionDict[Object.keys(selectionDict)[0]]]
```

To make things clear:

```js
Object.keys(selectionDict)[0]
```

returns the first key of the object `selectionDict` which is `Kcal`.

```js
selectionDict[Object.keys(selectionDict)[0]]
```

picks the value for the key `Kcal` which I have changed to `energy`.

Since your `item` object which you provide as a parameter to your `renderCard` function contains a key called `energy` we can access it with the picked key.

```js
item[selectionDict[Object.keys(selectionDict)[0]]]
```

I am not exactly sure why you have implemented it like this, since it seems rather complicated but it should work.

P.S.: Judging from the comments, I have assumed that your `item` object looks similar to the following.

```js
{
    energy: 200,
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This works! I see your comment "I am not exactly sure why you have implemented it like this, since it seems rather complicated but it should work." Is there an easier way to do this? I am new to react-native and eager to learn